# command prompt in asp.net and execute file in asp

Tags: asp.net, shell, command-prompt

I have a little asp.net program that in this program i could write and run commands of command prompt in my asp.net application An important part of this story is to run exe files with commands.
It is my code but dont run exe file for example where i write mspaint it dont open:

```
<pre lang="c#">
 try
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

            p.StartInfo.FileName = c_path.Value = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(c_path.Value));
            c_text.Value = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(c_text.Value));
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = c_text.Value;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            p.Start();

            string[] Uoc = new string[20];
            for (int i = 1; Uoc.Length &gt; i; i++)
            {
                Uoc[i] = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                Uoc[i] = Uoc[i].Replace("&lt;", "&lt;");
                Uoc[i] = Uoc[i].Replace("&gt;", "&gt;");
                Uoc[i] = Uoc[i].Replace("\r\n", "&lt;br&gt;");


            }

            string txt = "";
            foreach (var item in Uoc)
            {
                txt += item + "&lt;br /&gt;";
            }
            cmd_response.InnerHtml = "&lt;hr width=\"100%\" noshade/&gt;&lt;pre&gt;" + txt + "";
            cmd_response.Visible = true;
            more.Visible = true;

        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            xseuB(error.Message);
        }
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Task Manager and have it show processes for all users, you will see that the programs *do* run, but they are running under a different session.  As a security precaution, the sessions are independent of each other.  Programs in one session can not be interacted with by other sessions.